# Scorm 2004 cmi.interactions.n.description

Tags: scorm2004

I have used  cmi.interactions.n.description in my adaptor to get the question from a scorm package ..but i am not retrieving the particular questions..

Please help me to find the solution..

regards

Arun Krishnan G

Answer (score 1):

Arun,

You can only retrieve interactions that you have previously set. Is that the problem here?

If not, we need some more detail.

Mike